# installation of vmadditions.iso on virtual pc 2007

Tags: virtual-machine

i could not install the additions from the iso file there seems to be a problem in mounting the file from the console.if you start the virtual machine and use the action tab to install or update the vitual machine additions it captures the iso file but then nothing happens. if you look under the cd tab the iso file shows as captured but you can do noting with it. i am using windows 7 pro 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting the ISO image on the host OS using something like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) then copying the files off the image, or extracting the files from the ISO image with [WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/)

You could then copy the files through the network to the guest if that's working, or through some form of shared folder system - not sure what VPC has.